# findstr cannot use start and end of line

Tags: cmd, findstr

I don't get it; the **FINDSTR** usage is clear, but I can't get it to work. I want to **FINDSTR** on a text file, using the `^` and the `$` character. This way:

```
findstr /C:"^test$" test.txt
```

I have made the file (test.txt) in several ways (all on Windows), and there is no trailing space, but still, it doesn't find a matching line.

And it does work without `^` and `$`.

But it obviously ignores any characters or positions before and after `test`.

I want to match only lines containing just `test` and nothing else.

Why does the command not work as expected?

Comment: Are you trying to find a line with only the word "test" on it or are you trying to find lines that start with "test" and/or end with "test"?

Comment: In the simple example, I'm looking for a line that contains only the word "test". Of course I also want to look for lines with multiple words (and thus: spaces), but if this doesn't work, extended scenario's either won't.

Comment: Try `findstr /r /c:"^test$" test.txt` since you are using a regex.

Answer (score 3):

As an additional note, findstr expects CR-LF line endings. If your file uses simple linefeeds, it will not properly process the `$` metacharacter.

Comment: After 5 hours of wondering why `findstr` is not working properly, now I know ‍♂️

Comment: If this is important, you can try my `eol` tool to convert line endings first and then pipe the result to findstr like so:

    eol \r\n < README.md | findstr -r -c:"^directory.$"

You can find my `eol` tool at https://github.com/hollasch/eol.

Answer (score 2):

The [findstr documentation of Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459.aspx) is indeed not the best. The [SS64 documentation for findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) is much better and contains the section **Default type of search: Literal vs Regular Expression** explaining when **FINDSTR** runs by default a literal and when a regular expression find if not explicitly defined with `/L` for literal **OR** `/R` for regular expression.

There are several solutions for this task to match only entire lines case-sensitive as by default which can be changed to case-insensitive with `/I`.

The first one was given already by [apandit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888250/apandit).

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^test$" test.txt
```

This runs a regular expression find which matches and outputs only lines containing just the word `test` case-sensitive and nothing else as expected.

Another solution also using a regular expression find is

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe "^test$" test.txt
```

Yes, without `/C:` and because of search string containing the meta-characters `^` and `$`, this find is executed as regular expression find.

One more solution would be using a literal find which should output only lines matching entirely the specified search string.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /X /C:"test" test.txt
```

The same result would produce also this literal search.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /B /E /L /C:test test.txt
```

The parameter `/L` is not really needed because in this case the find is by default literal. But I think, it is good practice to always specify `/L` **OR** `/R` to make it clear for **FINDSTR** as well as for the reader of the command which find is executed: a literal or a regular expression find.

Comment: The reason I got confused about this was not understanding that `/R` doesn't clash with `/C:string`, given the help of `/C:string` says, "`/C:string`  Uses specified string as a _**literal**_ search string"; if they just dropped the word `literal`, it would have been so much clearer.